# How to append a new row to an old CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, writer

I am trying to add a new row to my old CSV file. Basically, it gets updated each time I run the Python script.

Right now I am storing the old CSV rows values in a list and then deleting the CSV file and creating it again with the new list value.

I wanted to know are there any better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 350):

```
with open('document.csv','a') as fd:
    fd.write(myCsvRow)
```

Opening a file with the `'a'` parameter allows you to append to the end of the file instead of simply overwriting the existing content. Try that.

Comment: I tried
fp = open(csv_filepathwithname, 'wa')
    writer = csv.writer(fp) 
    somelist = [ 3,56,3,6,56]
    writer.writerow((somelist))
but only the last row get append in the file.

Comment: The method assumes that the items being appended are comma separated, which may not always be the case. Then the write method will not maintain the csv delimiter. The answer below is more robust in that sense.

Comment: Please provide myCsvRow type

Answer (score 250):

I prefer this solution using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv) module from the standard library and the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement to avoid leaving the file open.

The key point is using `'a'` for appending when you open the file.

```
import csv   
fields=['first','second','third']
with open(r'name', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
```

If you are using Python 2.7 you may experience superfluous new lines in Windows. You can try to avoid them using `'ab'` instead of `'a'` this will, however, cause you [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in python and CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283178/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-python-and-csv) in Python 3.6. Adding the `newline=''`, as Natacha suggests, will cause you [a backward incompatibility between Python 2 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206233/python-2-and-3-csv-module-text-binary-mode-backwards-compatibility).

Comment: Annoying issue that can arise: If the csv file doesn't end with a newline, this will extend the final row instead of adding a new one.

Comment: This is the better answer to the question, and should be marked as correct answer.
The csv package ensures formatting correctly, in fact I can't think of any advantage of using plain text over csv.

Comment: For me this code was adding superfluous new lines so I added a ```newline=''``` to this row: ```with open(r'name', 'a', newline='') as f:``` (windows, python 3.9)

Answer (score 37):

Based in the answer of @G M and paying attention to the @John La Rooy's warning, I was able to append a new row opening the file in `'a'`mode.

> Even in windows, in order to avoid the newline problem, you must declare it as `newline=''`.
>
> Now you can open the file in `'a'`mode (without the b).

```
import csv

with open(r'names.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['This','aNew']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writerow({'This':'is', 'aNew':'Row'})
```

I didn't try with the regular writer (without the Dict), but I think that it'll be ok too.

Answer (score 22):

If you use pandas, you can append your dataframes to an existing CSV file this way:

```
df.to_csv('log.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

With mode='a' we ensure that we append, rather than overwrite, and with header=False we ensure that we append only the values of df rows, rather than header + values.

Answer (score 15):

Are you opening the file with mode of 'a' instead of 'w'?

See [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the python docs

> ## 7.2. Reading and Writing Files
>
> open() returns a file object, and is most commonly used with two arguments: open(filename, mode).
>
> ```
> >>> f = open('workfile', 'w')
> >>> print f <open file 'workfile', mode 'w' at 80a0960>
> ```
>
> The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second argument is
> another string containing a few characters describing the way in which
> the file will be used. mode can be 'r' when the file will only be
> read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will
> be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to
> the file is automatically added to the end. 'r+' opens the file for
> both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; 'r' will be
> assumed if it’s omitted.
>
> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
> there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows
> makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line
> characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data
> is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data
> is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that
> in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading
> and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to
> the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary
> files.

Comment: may be you could make your answer more elaborated, then it would look like a real answer :-)

Comment: @user, I added a link - does that help you?

Answer (score 12):

If the file exists and contains data, then it is possible to generate the `fieldname` parameter for `csv.DictWriter` automatically:

```
# read header automatically
with open(myFile, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for header in reader:
        break

# add row to CSV file
with open(myFile, "a", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writerow(myDict)
```

Answer (score 12):

I use the following approach to append a new line in a .csv file:

```
pose_x = 1 
pose_y = 2

with open('path-to-your-csv-file.csv', mode='a') as file_:
    file_.write("{},{}".format(pose_x, pose_y))
    file_.write("\n")  # Next line.
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- `mode='a'` is append mode.

Comment: Is it possible to loop thru rows and append a new row under each row this way?

Comment: @santma Yes, it is. You can use a `for` to do that.

Answer (score 6):

```
# I like using the codecs opening in a with 
field_names = ['latitude', 'longitude', 'date', 'user', 'text']
with codecs.open(filename,"ab", encoding='utf-8') as logfile:
    logger = csv.DictWriter(logfile, fieldnames=field_names)
    logger.writeheader()

# some more code stuff 

    for video in aList:
        video_result = {}                                     
        video_result['date'] = video['snippet']['publishedAt']
        video_result['user'] = video['id']
        video_result['text'] = video['snippet']['description'].encode('utf8')
        logger.writerow(video_result)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Answers also benefit from an explanation - and these answers also attract more upvotes.

Comment: This is some simple code, it opens the file for append mode, writes out a header rec and then works through the video records in aList.