# When I write to a CSV file, the stored data is deleted and replaced with the new data

Tags: python, csv

I try to write to a CSV file but when i check the file, only th last set of data is displayed? How can this be fixed?
 my original code is:

```
highscores=open("Highscores.csv","w")
toPrint=(name+","+score+"\n")
for z in toPrint:
    highscores.write(z)
highscores.close()
```

and I also tried this:

```
toPrint=[]
output=(name+","+score+"\n")
toPrint.append(output)
for z in toPrint:
    highscores.write(z)
 highscores.close()
```

Comment: What do you think this `toPrint=(name+","+score+"\n")` is doing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2363742/5203702

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the file in "Append" mode instead of the "Write". Your code will remain the same only the following line will change:

```
highscores=open("Highscores.csv","a")
```