# Python: Repeatedly writing to a csv file from a dictionary with header equal to key

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am using a dictionary to store scraped values from a table. Then I am writing a row to a csv file. I want to write new rows to a csv file which includes the key as the headers.

I want to write the data to a file mydict.csv, like this:

```
key1, key2, key3,
value_a, value_b, value_c
```

I wrote:

```
import csv

def dict_to_csv(scraped_values_dict): 

    my_dict = scraped_values_dict
     with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

This method overwrites the previous values. I'd like instead to set the header of the csv file as the keys and with each function call, add a new row with the values. I only want to write the header if the file is empty.

```
key1, key2, key3, 
value_a, value_b, value_c,
value_d, value_e, value_f
```

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363731/append-new-row-to-old-csv-file-python

Comment: 2 lines in pandas if you are web scraping the table and not processing further. `df=pd.read_html(url); df.to_csv(filename)` done.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate as I would only like to write the header if the file is empty

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
import csv

def dict_to_csv(scraped_values_dict): 
    my_dict = scraped_values_dict
    with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'a') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
        if f.tell() == 0:
            w.writeheader()
            w.writerow(my_dict)
        else: 
            w.writerow(my_dict)
```