# Add new line to output in csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I am a newbie at Python & I have a web scraper program that retrieved links and puts them into a .csv file. I need to add a new line after each web link in the output but I do not know how to use the \n properly. Here is my code:

```
  file = open('C:\Python34\census_links.csv', 'a')
  file.write(str(census_links))  
  file.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to answer your question without knowing the format of the variable `census_links`.

But presuming it is a `list` that contains multiple links composed of `strings`, you would want to parse through each link in the list and append a newline character to the end of a given link and then write that link + newline to the output file:

```
file = open('C:/Python34/census_links.csv', 'a')

# Simulating a list of links:
census_links = ['example.com', 'sample.org', 'xmpl.net']

for link in census_links: 
    file.write(link + '\n')       # append a newline to each link
                                  # as you process the links

file.close()         # you will need to close the file to be able to 
                     # ensure all the data is written.
```

Comment: `print(x, file=f)` is another way to do `f.write(x + '\n')`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist ... what you say is definitely true, thanks for sharing. I opted to try to stay as close to the OP's original code layout as I could to minimize the cognitive load.

Comment: That's probably a good idea. I'll just leave the comment here for posterity.

Comment: Thank you so much! These were in a set but this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

[E. Ducateme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3780372/e-ducateme) has already answered the question, but you could also use the csv module (most of the code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363731/append-new-row-to-old-csv-file-python)):

```
import csv

# This is assuming that “census_links” is a list
census_links = ["Example.com", "StackOverflow.com", "Google.com"]
file = open('C:\Python34\census_links.csv', 'a')
writer = csv.writer(file)

for link in census_links:
    writer.writerow([link])
```