# append new row with CSV path as a string object Python

Tags: python, csv, row

I am searching how to append a new row to CSV in Python. What I want is that the path to be predefined as a string object. I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363731/append-new-row-to-old-csv-file-python):

```
import csv   
fields=['first','second','third']
with open(r'name', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
```

what I want is something like this in modified in the above implementation

```
path='home/user/new.csv'
import csv   
fields=['first','second','third']
with open(rpath , 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
```

I can't seem to do it because of the letter *r* appearing in argument besides path. Can anybody guide on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original snippet you referred, the `r` prefix tells python to treat the string as a raw string and leave the backslashes in the string. (Refer https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals for a detailed explanation)

So r can be prefixed only before a string literal like this `r'somestring'`.

In your example, you are defining the variable name as `path`. But later you are calling it as rpath. `rpath` is not defined anywhere in your code. So it will throw an error. 
You can change it to

```
with open(path , 'a') as f:
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose below is your new.csv file and you want to add a row `new_row` as a fourth row the CSV :

```
$ cat  new.csv
SN, Num1, Num2
1, one, two
2, three, four
3, five, six
```

Below code will do that..

```
$ cat appendCsv2.py
#!/isr/bin/python3
import csv

new_row =['4', 'first','second','third']
with open('new.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(new_row)
csvFile.close()
```

Output desired:

```
$ cat new.csv
SN, Num1, Num2
1, one, two
2, three, four
3, five, six
4,first,second,third
```

Don't forget to close the file!

From [Python Document](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)
It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks:

```
>>> with open('workfile', 'r') as f:
...     read_data = f.read()
>>> f.closed
True
```

Comment: Another question; I thought if we are using _with open_ , it is not required to close the file as it automatically closes after exiting the indentation?

Comment: @Osama,  agreed, Within the with statement the __enter__ method on open(...) is called and as soon as you go out of that block the `__exit__` method is called `(self.close())`. As for the f.close() after, it's not wrong but useless. It's already closed so it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
import csv

path='/home/user/new.csv'
fields=['first','second','third']
# To prevent newline by writerow(), open with newline=""
with open(path , 'a', newline="") as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(fields)
```