# How to write a new row in an existing csv file without appending it in the last line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to add a new row to an existing .csv file in python.

I tried by the following by appending a line to the csv file in spyder IDE in windows.

```
def write_to_file():

file = open('E:/Python/Sample//Dataset.csv','a')   
file.write(",".join([str(newID),request.form['username'],request.form['age']]))

file.close()
```

I expect the new values in a new row. But it is appending the new values in the last row.

If i add name "Erick" and Age "60", the output looks like the below image.[image]

But I expect something like the below.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you write a newline before the row?

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry. I want to add the row in order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [append new row to old csv file python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363731/append-new-row-to-old-csv-file-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is correct, but you're assuming that the file already ends with a new line character

You need to put `file.write("\n")` before and/or after you've written each line

Comment: Careful that if your file already ends with a newline, then you shouldn't write another one. Otherwise, you would then have empty lines... In such cases, using CSV as a "database replacement" is not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version would be:

```
import csv

row =['Eric', '60']

with open('people.csv','a') as csvFile:   #a to append to existing csv file
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    csvFile.write("\n")    #write your data to new line
    writer.writerow(row)
csvFile.close()
```

Output (assuming your csv Doesn't end on new line):

[image]

Please be warned (If your csv ends on a newline) the output will have additional space:

[image]

Comment: I checked it. It's working fine and it's not adding additional space.

Comment: Notice how prior "Before" image has 3 lines, whereas the later "before" text has 4 lines. If your csv ends on newline it will add space