# Writing in specific columns in csv file in python

Tags: python, file, csv

I want to write my output code in csv file in this way, first column in csv contain file name and second column contain the value of exetime (s2) , how can do that?

```
 inputpath = 'C:/Users/mach/Desktop/hh/c*.csv'
    for file in iglob(inputpath):
        s1 = time.time()
        size = function(file) 
        s2 = time.time() - s1 
        with open(r'C:/Users/mach/Desktop/exetime.csv','a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow({file,s2})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363731/append-new-row-to-old-csv-file-python

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that, I need to write the file name in  first column  and s2 

         in second column

Comment: use two `writer.writerow(....)`

Comment: @Shijith, can you see my update, its ok writhing in two columns but in unarranged way!

Comment: use `writer.writerow([file,s2])` please define `but in unarranged way`. please refer the third answer or the above link if you are using windows and having a newline problem

Comment: OK ,I solve it, just I replased {} in [ ], but I have empty rows between the filled rows!

Comment: please refer the third answer or the above link if you are using windows and having a newline problem add `newline=''` inside your open function

Comment: Thanks a lot, you can put your comment as answer to get an acceptance answer  :)

Comment: ok  added as answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSV file written with Python has blank lines between each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do as below.  refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363731/append-new-row-to-old-csv-file-python)

```
with open(r'C:/Users/mach/Desktop/exetime.csv','a',newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow([file,s2])
```

`newline=''` is to avoid writing a unwanted newline (line ending is `\r\n` on Windows)