# Append row to csv writes on same line

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to add a row to an existing `.csv` file (rows have the same format).

Here is my code:

```
sample = {"Language": "Francais","Description": "question sur les cost-centers"}

to_add = [sample['Language'], sample['Description']]
with open('train_tickets.csv', mode='a', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    w.writerow(to_add)
```

The output (see image below) writes on the same line:

[Last Row of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqm0t.png)

While I would like them to be appended to a new row:

[Intended Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qseor.png)

Does anyone know what's wrong in my code? Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363731/append-new-row-to-old-csv-file-python

Comment: Should read `writerows(...`, because you want to write a list of rows