# How can I append new data into my .csv file without deleting the previous data

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I made a maths quiz where the program asks and stores the user's name, the question, the solution and the user's score into a .csv file. My problem is that whenever the program is run the newly inputted data overwrites the previous data set, which I don't want so instead I want the new data to be appended below the old data set. How can I do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
import csv
import random

Name = input("Enter your name: ")
score = 0

a = random.randint(1,100)
b = random.randint(1,100)
Q1 = int(input(str(a) + " + " + str(b) + " = "))
A1 = a + b

x = random.randint(1,100)
y = random.randint(1,100)
Q2 = int(input(str(x) + " - " + str(y) + " = "))
A2 = x - y

if Q1 == A1:
    score1 = score + 1
else:
    score1 = score


if Q2 == A2:
    score2 = score + 1

else:
    score2 = score

with open("Quiz.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow([Name, "Question", "Solution", "Mark"])

    writer.writerow([1, str(a) + " + " + str(b) , A1, score1])
    writer.writerow([2, str(x) + " - " + str(y) , A2, score2])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+ in built-in open function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [append new row to old csv file python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363731/append-new-row-to-old-csv-file-python)

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, please accept it.

Comment: @JakeBoggs Yes it did, thanks

Comment: That's great, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the file in append mode, like this:

```
with open("Quiz.csv", "a", newline="") as file:
```

Comment: What would I need to do then?

Comment: Replace "w" with "a"