# How to row wise append two .csv files without using pandas

Tags: python, csv, with-statement

I want to append two .csv files with the same number/names of columns and save the ouput file. However I don't want to use pandas concat nor pandas read_csv. Is there a way to achieve this using pure python 'with open'?

Comment: Check out this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363731/append-new-row-to-old-csv-file-python). They are just trying to append data, but you can open the second file within the loop and append it to the first.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
# read first file
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as txt:
    lines = txt.readlines()

# extend the list with the lines from the second file
with open('file2.csv', 'r') as txt:
    lines.extend(txt.readlines())

# remove \n from the end of each line
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
```