# Write multiple results to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I'm using selenium and beautifulsoup to iterate through a number of webpages and sort out the results. I have that working, however I want to export the results to a CSV using this block of code:

```
with open('finallist.csv', mode='w') as final_list:
    stock_writer = csv.writer(final_list, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    stock_writer.writerow([ticker, element.get_text()])
```

The only issue is, with the result being multiple different things, this code as it stands just replaces the first line of the CSV every time a new result comes in. Is there any way I can have it write to a new line each time?

Comment: `mode='w'` means to create a new file, or truncate one if it exists.  `mode='a'` will append to an existing file (or create a new one if it doesn't exist)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [append new row to old csv file python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363731/append-new-row-to-old-csv-file-python)

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Python documentation for the `open()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), you can pass the `'a'` mode to the `open()` function. Doing so will append any text to the end of the file, if the file already exists.

```py
with open('finallist.csv', mode='a') as final_list:
    ...
```