# How to append row to a saved .csv file via Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, append

I am new to python and have been actively learning for a few weeks. I decided to apply some of the this I learned to try and develop a fictional patient logging program.

I have figured out how to capture inputs from the terminal and save them into a CVS file. Now I was trying to figure out a way to append (aka add on to that document)the file without overwriting the data that is already stored on the .csv file. The method I am using via pandas keeps failing. below is my code so far. I hope you can help.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
test_list = ['Full', 'Spiro/Gas', 'Spiro', 'Spiro + Rev']

while True:
    # Caputring the data 
    first_name = input('First Name: ') 
    if first_name == 'quit':
        exit()
    second_name = input('Second Name: ')
    hosp_No = input('CaseNote Number: ')
    gender = input('Male(M) or Female (F): ')
    yob = int(input('YOB: '))
    test = input('Whats test?: ')
# Prepping table parameters for Panadas
    titled_columns = {"Date": [date],
                      "First Name": [first_name],
                      "Second Name": [second_name],
                      "Casenote NO": [hosp_No],
                      "Gender": [gender],
                      "Year of Birth": [yob],
                      "Test": [test]}

# OUTPUT and Attempted Appending --- Please help
    pt_log_data = pd.DataFrame(titled_columns)

    new_pt_line = pd.DataFrame.append(titled_columns[0], ignore_index=True)

    pt_log_data.to_csv('PFT_Log.csv')

    print("Patient Information Saved")
```

Comment: you want to append pt_log_data table to 'PFT_Log.csv' which is already in your system?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363731/append-new-row-to-old-csv-file-python .

Comment: Thanks for the help