# How to make my python script not overwrite a CSV files existing data when executing again

Tags: python, csv, fopen

I am writing a Python script to write data to a CSV file. The data is passed by parameter, for which I use the argparse library. It is also important that the data has a certain order so that it matches the CSV header. Another feature of the script is that the user does not know all the data at once, but learns it over a period of time. This means that the user can specify the data for the CSV in any order and the script then orders them so that they have the correct order in the CSV as mentioned.

An example: There are parameters `a` and `b`.

Within the CSV, the data of parameter `a` must come before that of parameter `b`

However, the user executes the script with parameter `b` first because he does not yet know the data of parameter `a`.

In addition, the data should be retained in the CSV, even if not all parameters are specified.

My problem is as follows

1. I can't manage to write the parameter data in the correct order in the CSV script.

2. In addition, the script overwrites the data of the previous execution in the CSV if I no longer specify the previous parameter (it thinks that if I no longer specify the parameter that it has the value “n/a" and overwrites the data in the field with “n/a").

Also to mention: I'm not very experienced in Python, so I hope this problem won't hold you up too long.

Here is an example of my script. It should work like this and show what I described above.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from pathlib import Path
import csv

# creating parser and the arguments
# nargs='?' means that the parameter is optional
parser = ArgumentParser()
# data before drive
# ---
parser.add_argument('--file', type=Path)
parser.add_argument('--data1', type=str, nargs="?", default="n/a")
parser.add_argument('--data2', type=str, nargs="?", default="n/a")
parser.add_argument('--date', type=str, nargs="?", default="n/a")

# parse arguments into "args" var
args = parser.parse_args()

# specify rows and fields of the csv file
fields = ['Driver', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Date']
rows = {'Drive Number': args.driveNr, 'Data 1': args.data1, 'Data 2': args.data2, 'Date': args.date}

# open the csvfile and write the parameters value inside
with open(args.file, 'r+') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, rows.keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(rows)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append a new row to an old CSV file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363731/how-to-append-a-new-row-to-an-old-csv-file-in-python)

Comment: Are you saying you run "script.py --file some.csv --data1 123" and *then* run "script.py --file some.csv --data2 234" and expect the file to update a partial line?  Unclear what you are asking.  Provide execution steps that exhibit the problem, and exactly what the desired outcome should be.

Comment: You can read the original CSV into a list of dictionaries, update the dictionaries, then overwrite the file with the new data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MarkTolonen yes this is exactly what I’m looking for. `main.py  —file data.csv —data1 123 —data2 456` should append the data to the file. But if I want to add `data3` by just executing `main.py —file data.csv —data3 789`, I want to do this without `data1` and `data2` getting deleted. So yes, additionally to that I want to update a particular line because the order needs to be right too.